# Zend_Session e Zend_Pagination com form pesquisa

Tags: php, zend

Estou com problemas em uma paginação com pesquisa via formulário no Zend Framework 1.

Existe um método na model que faz uma query com where para trazer o resultado conforme a pesquisa feita, e a paginação se for feita sem sessão funciona apenas a primeira página, pois as demais não traz os resultados conforme filtro.

Depois de dias pesquisando e ainda sem solução, vi que posso tentar realmente usar a sessão pra tentar sanar esse problema, mas não estou entendendo como aplicar isso.

Tenho o seguinte controller:

```
public function consultarAction()
    {

        $setor = $this->_getParam('setor');

        $modLotacao = new Sca_Model_Lotacao('sca');

        $resultado = $modLotacao->getConsultaTelefones($setor);

        $busca = new Zend_Session_Namespace($resultado);

        if ($this->_request->isPost()) {
            $busca->unsetAll();
            $busca->busca = $this->_request->getPost();
        }

        $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($resultado($busca->busca));
        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
        $paginator->setPageRange(7);
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber(intval($this->_request->getParam('pagina', 1)));

        $this->view->paginator = $paginator;    

    }
```

Isso está me retornando erro, mas realmente deve está algo errado que não sei =\

De qualquer forma, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu já resolvi este problema de filtros na paginação sem *session*, apenas passando parâmetros. Segue a solução:

### Controller

Pega a lista e monta o *paginator*:

```
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($lista);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(12)->setCurrentPageNumber($this->getParam('p', 1));
$paginator->setPageRange(5);
$this->view->assign('lista', $paginator);
```

Envia a busca pra *view* também:

```
$this->view->assign('busca', $this->getParam('busca'));
```

### View da *action*

Imprime o layout da paginação, passando a busca no 4º parâmetro:

```
echo $this->paginationControl($this->lista, 'Sliding', 'pagination.phtml', array('busca' => $this->busca));
```

### View da paginação

Na *view* da paginação (normalmente `pagination.phtml`), recebe o parâmetro com os filtros:

```
$filtros = $this->busca
```

...e concatena eles nos *links* da paginação.

Comment: Eu resolvi mesmo com Sessão, mas é bom esse teu aí, e quem sabe alguém agora vai ter mais facilidade um dia. Porque foi muito difícil achar alguma solução pratica disso. Obrigado!

Comment: Tive alguns problemas com o uso da sessão... pq quando apago o registro ele não ta sumindo, até pq to usando o forward conforme postei outro link aí. @Lucas não entendi bem essa tua aplicação aí sem session.

Comment: Não entendi essa aplicação em cima do que fiz, vc ainda usou a $busca da sessão?

Comment: Não. A busca vem por parâmetro (GET ou POST), utilizando `getParam()`. Daí envia essa busca pra *view* (assign) e passa ela por parâmetro para o *script* da paginação.

Comment: Malz, mas não estou conseguindo implementar isso muito bem. =\

Comment: A tua busca vem por GET? Tu tem um pagination.phtml?

Comment: Via POST e sim tenho pagination.phtml  ---

<?php if (isset($this->next)): ?>

          <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->next)); ?>" aria-label="Next" >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>

Comment: Então, vai fazendo por partes como eu escrevi na resposta, passando de um script para o outro, até que tu recebe lá no pagination.phtml e concatena no link

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21083/discussion-between-phpricardo-and-lucas).